# Access variables returned from function in django view with name of variable

Tags: python, django

I have a view in django that has a filter that uses two dates. I want to calculate the dates in a separate function to tidy it up a bit and return them to the view.

```
def index(request):
    function = month()
    objectcount = Entry.objects.filter(entrydate__range=(function[0], function[1])).count() #bleurgh!
    context = {
        "objectcount": objectcount,
    }
    return render(request, 'entry/index.html', context)

def month():
    today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    first_of_month = "{}-{}-01".format(today.year, today.month)
    last = calendar.monthrange(today.year, today.month)[1]
    last_of_month = "{}-{}-{}".format(today.year, today.month, last)

    return first_of_month, last_of_month
```

This works fine, but I have to access the variables using `function[0]` and `function[1]`.

How can I pass these variables so they are accessed from the index view using names - like `first_of_month` and `last_of_month`?

Comment: pass them as tuples `return (first_of_month, last_of_month)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you write like this

```
def month():
    today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    first_of_month = "{}-{}-01".format(today.year, today.month)
    last = calendar.monthrange(today.year, today.month)[1]
    last_of_month = "{}-{}-{}".format(today.year, today.month, last)
    resp_data ={"first_of_month":first_of_month,"last_of_month":last_of_month}
    return resp_data
```

`function["first_of_month"]`
`function["last_of_month"]`

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass them as tuples

   `return (first_of_month, last_of_month)`

and access it via index.

2. pass them as a dictionary like

   `var ={"a":a,"b":b}
   return var`